# MVC comparing changes to existing values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I've currently got a bit of an issue when trying to check values that have been posted as part of an update, to what is currently being held in the database.

Currently what i'm doing is reading the existing record into a new variable, alongside the one passed in from the post, and checking values in that variable. However I've just noticed that as soon as I read the record from the database, the values passed in from the post get reset to their previous value.

I have a feeling that the reason is that the posted record and the retrieved record both have the same primary key value, and so the code is then overwriting the new values as there can't be two different objects with the same primary key in memory. Though that is just a guess.

Can someone help me with this issue, and possibly help me find a way to get around this?

**EDIT:**

My code is below. This is the main code, and as soon as I retrieve the "original record", the values in the "faultrecord" get reverted to what they were before

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(fault faultrecord)
    {
        fault originalRecord = _faultRepository.Read(faultrecord.ID); /*here is where it gets reverted*/

        if (faultrecord != originalRecord)
        {
            /*perform actions and update record*/
        }
    }
```

The below code is what I use to read the record from the database:

```
public fault Read(int id)
    {
        var result = ITJobEntities.faults.Where(t => t.ID == id);

        if (result.Any())
        {
            return result.FirstOrDefault();
        }

        return null;            
    }
```

My only reason for believing it to be to do with the primary keys is because when I added in the "originalRecord" retrieval, my update statement to the database started failing due to there being multiple objects with the same ID (the actual error was a bit more descriptive, but I can't remember it fully).

Comment: Two different object instances don't get updated with each other just because they share a primary key. C# has no notion of primary keys. There must be something else going on, for example you attaching the incoming object to the DbContext instance. Show some relevant code.

Comment: If your question is about ASP.NET MVC, rather than the generic Model View Controller pattern, please use the `asp.net-mvc` tag, not `model-view-controller`. I'd edit, but you also need to add more details (mostly a [mcve]) to your question anyway.

Comment: Have you overloaded the `==` and `!=` operators for your model. If not then `if (faultrecord != originalRecord)` will always be `true` - they are 2 different objects (it has nothing to do with the primary key). And your method need only one line of code - `return ITJobEntities.faults.Where(t => t.ID == id).FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: I think i've found what the problem is. My method of submitting the form ended up submitting it twice. So by the time I got to the point of it retrieving the existing data, it has been submitted again and seemingly reset the values on the object back to what they were originally. I've since fixed that problem and it is now working. Thanks for your suggestions though